# Why do urine have a chemical smell after drinking a lot of alcohol (red wine)?

Tags: alcohol

When I've been drinking a lot of red wine my urine starts to have a chemical smell. How do that urine differ from normal urine?
Is that chemical smell a sign of liver issues? When I was younger I don't remember my urine having that smell after or during drinking lots of alcohol.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: Also, personal medical questions are considered off-topic on this site. You should edit your question to be more broadly applicable and less about a personal medical experience. Otherwise, our community will likely vote to close the question. Please [edit] accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Its a very specific question and those are simply not on internet. You should know this.
You misunderstand. If it were a medical issue I would go to a real doctor and not ask sketchy strangers about it. Im asking because of curiosity.

Comment: What is your issue about how I formulated the question? Its short and to the point. I see no issue with it. Do you mean I should formulate it as a hypothetical question? That would be ridiculous nonsense and unnecessary.

Comment: Some things you can do to conform to our expectations here and to improve the response your question receives: 1) to avoid looking like a personal med question, indicate *explicitly* (i.e., by linking/citing specific examples) how others have experienced the same thing; 2) be more specific about the smell -- compare it to something; 3) to demonstrate research effort: do an extensive online search for your question (e.g., Google, Google Scholar, PubMed, NIH, etc.,) and *explicitly* report back where you looked (with which search terms), what you found out, and what you'd still like to know.